# Create a batch script that does the work of VLOOKUP for CSV files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two files: File11 and File22. Their first columns are similar and named **concatenatedValue**. I want to use this **concatenatedValue** column from File22 and search it in File11 and get the column values corresponding to it from File11. The result can be stored in a new CSV file e.g., output.csv.

I have written a batch script to complete this purpose but it's not working as expected. It opens a CMD window and is just stuck on it, neither showing any output nor anything else.

Also, the batch script code is below:

```
@REM vlookup kind of funtionality through batch script

@ECHO OFF

for /f "tokens=1 delims=, skip=1" %%i in (File22.csv) do @findstr  "%%i," File11.csv >nul & If errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1 (for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%m in ('findstr /i /L "%%i," File11.csv') do (@echo %%m,%%n>>output.csv
echo i value: %%i, m value: %%m, n value: %%n)) ELSE (echo %%i,NA>>output.csv)

cmd /k echo Hello
```

Please guide me in what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The first thing you should do, is remove the `@` characters, change ```ECHO OFF``` to ```ECHO ON```, and run it from a Command Prompt window, to see what's happening. BTW, I would start by replacing ```& If errorlevel 0 IF NOT errorlevel 1``` with `&&` and replacing ```) ELSE (``` with ```) || (```.

Comment: **1.** Do NOT post your data as an image. Post it here as text so we can copy it. How do you expect that we have example data to work with?  **2.** Please, post the desired output from your example input data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is *very* complicated... I would do it this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load File11 contents into File11 array using first column as array subscript
for /F "tokens=1* delims=, skip=1" %%i in (File11.csv) do set "File11[%%i]=%%j"

rem Process File22's first column and output values from same File11's first column
(for /F "tokens=1 delims=, skip=1" %%i in (File22.csv) do (
   if defined File11[%%i] (
      echo %%i,!File11[%%i]!
   ) else (
      echo %%i,NA
   )
)) > output.csv
```

You can review the method of process array elements in Batch at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)